# Sending automatic email based on date in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm doing a project. I'm new to coding and very new to SQL. I'm coding in C# / ASP.net and using Microsoft SQL Server. I was wondering if there was a way to automatically send emails to a user based on a recorded date column in a database.

Basically I have my application recording a time in one column of a database and the email in another column. Once that time column is 30 days old i want it to send an email to that user saying hey you account info is 30 days old go update it.

Comment: Not sure if this will accomplish what you need, but look into triggers:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Maybe, create a SQL Agent Job.  Run an agent job selecting those withing your date range, send the email...

SQL Mail setup:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-sql-server-agent-mail-to-use-database-mail?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Agent job is what you need. The job can run a stored procedure every day at a fixed time (or more frequently). The stored procedure that runs would then go check all the records with a date greater than 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Current answers suggest to create a sql trigger to send an email.  I disagree with this approach.  Sql triggers are not a silver bullet, and do you really want to make your sql server responsible for emails as well?

Instead, I would generally recommend instead to create a timer or scheduled job with ASP.NET that will will run daily and pull all users that you're going to send an email to.

Then process that email at will.